# How do i render black light effects on the object?

Tags: shaders, blender-internal-render-engine, lighting, shader-nodes

[image]

No matter what I tried to make the object render for the black light it just goes wrong.

Like if you want the object to glow florescent under the ultraviolet light, not the shadows or the darker shade but the exposer to the lamp.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148887/how-to-simulate-a-blacklight-effect https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166425/blacklight-cfl-bulb-effect

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you are trying to use Blender 2.79 and its old internal render engine, any reason to use that instead of any more modern versions with Eevee or Cycles?